# Intel driver issues on 20.04 (can't change driver, screen tearing)

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

I have been trying to change my graphics driver, as I am getting some really bad screen tearing on my Intel laptop.

I have tried following the tutorials I found online, such as the ones that tell you to create a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` called `20-intel.conf`. I attempted to use many different settings, such as doing the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Option "TripleBuffer" "true"
    Option "DRI" "false"
EndSection
```

as well as different combinations of the settings above, like having just the identifier, driver and `TearFree` option in this file. Each change I made just made it worse; there were visual artefacts on the screen and the framerates were terrible. I have also tried setting the driver to 'modesetting' as some sites suggested, but that also didn't help.

If it helps, when I run `inxi -G`, even with the above settings, it still says I am using the i915 driver:

```
bartek@Laptop:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that the solution to this was to disable fractional scaling. To sort-of avoid looking at a tiny screen, I instead increased my font scaling to 1.25 and left my screen scaling at 100% and now everything is perfect.